# Questions in reported speech from direct speech

Tags: grammaticality, tense, reported-speech

**Direct speech:**

> Do you love me?

**Reported speech:**

> She asked if I loved her?

**Or**

> She asked did I love her?

Please let me know, which one is a correct answer? Or both are fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: She asked if I loved her. - Without the question mark, is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer is most likely, "She asked me if I love her." but the other one is ok.

I think you missed the important part.  What's the correct answer to say back to her?  The woman talks in code.  The answer to "Do you love me?" is very difficult and advanced.  It all depends on which word is stressed, which indicates uneasiness or doubt.

Her: "**Do** you love me?" Then she has doubts about the honest of your love.  Maybe your capability.
Correct Answer: "Of **course** I love you.  If I didn't love you, I would have been gone a long time ago.  I'll always love you."

But they get harder....

Her: "Do **you** love me?" Then she has doubts about the **you** loving her.
Correct Answer:  "I love you like I've nover loved anyone in my life.  Yes *I* love you!"
Her: "Buy why do you love me?"
You: "Because your special.  You're kind.  You love people.  You're the best girl I've ever met.  You're beautiful on the inside and out.  You drive me crazy!"

Her: "Do you **love** me?" Then she doubt about your **love** for her.
Correct Answer:  "I always love you.  My heart is yours forever.  I've never stopped and I never will."
Her: "Then why didn't you do X" where "X" is something you never would have thought doing, like stacking her dishes to the left.
You: "Because I wanted to make you mad."
Her: "Whaaat?"
You" "I'm joooking!  I didn't know that was important.  You know I try to be a mindreader.  I'm just not good enough at it yet.  I want more practice.  My energies say you want a shoulder rub right now."
Her: "That's not what I was thinking..."
You: "I know what your *mind* was thinking, But your body was screaming for a shoulder rub..."

Her:  "Do you love **me**?  Then she has some doubt or insecurity about herself.
Correct Answer: "Yes I love you.  You're the only one I love.  I love everything about you.  I love your eyes, your smile, your face, you laugh.  But most of all, I - LOVE - YOU!"
Her: "Then what about that girl you were talking to?"
You: "Which one?   I talk to so many..."  She hits you playfully.  "Owww!" you say with more pain and flinching that it really hurt.  "Don't be so jealous/silly/whatever, I was asking her what I should get you for a present."